# Java: Convert Generic typed (T) object to a fully typed object that is recognized by a typed call signature?

Tags: java, generics, types

Given

```java
private someMethod(String value) {
 // do string things
}

private someMethod(Integer value) {
 // do number things
}
```

Would the following work to call the proper `someMethod` depending on the type of `clazz` and the value of `input` ?

```java
public <T> void doSomething(T input, Class<T> clazz) {
    // Cast the input to the type specified by clazz
    // Call a method that expects a parameter of the type specified by clazz
    someMethod(clazz.cast(input));
}
```

if it can't be done this way, what is the best way to do this without getting into a long if/else of hard checks on static typed constants?

Comment: No. You would need to do the dispatching of `someMethod` manually.

Comment: You cannot actually do this, really.

Comment: Overloaded methods are resolved at compile time. They are essentially completely different methods that happen to share a name.

Comment: If `input` cannot be `null`, you are not going to need the `Class<T>` parameter since you can always do `input.getClass()` inside your method to get the concrete runtime type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use reflection API to achieve that.

```
public <T> void someMethod(Object value, Class<T> clazz) {
    try {
        getClass().getDeclaredMethod("someMethod", clazz).invoke(this, value);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException | NoSuchMethodException | SecurityException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**First (and quick) "solution"**

Actually, there is no Java built-in mechanism that handles this dispatching for you. That means, you have to do it yourself.

But ... to avoid a longer if-else chain, you can use a mapping that maps the type to the consuming method you want to call. Example:

```
private final Map<Class<?>, Consumer<?>> dispatcher = new HashMap<>();

{
    dispatcher.put(String.class, (String value) -> someMethod(value));
    dispatcher.put(Integer.class, (Integer value) -> someMethod(value));
}
```

Now you can do the following:

```
public <T> void doSomething(T input, Class<T> clazz) {
    Consumer<T> consumer = (Consumer<T>) dispatcher.get(clazz);
    if (consumer != null) consumer.accept(input);
}
```

Be careful when building the dispatcher map. Any mistake there will result in a  runtime error when calling the method `doSomething`. There is even a compiler warning for this.

Not perfect, but maybe a way to go ...

**Further considerations**

This manual dispatching is a great hint for you that there might be more OOP like solution. Usually, there is a *type* lurking behind your thoughts ...

So first create an interface for that type:

```
interface SomethingDoable {
    void someMethod();
}
```

Note, that the generic type is also eliminated here. Now you can create some classes for that:

```
class StringDoable implements SomethingDoable {
    private final String value;
    public StringDoable(String value) { this.value = value; }
    @Override public void doSomething() { /* your code here using the string value */ }
}

class IntegerDoable implements SomethingDoable {
    private final Integer value;
    public IntegerDoable(Integer value) { this.value = value; }
    @Override public void doSomething() { /* your code here using the integer value */ }
}
```

With that preparation, you can simplify your public method:

```
public void doSomething(SomethingDoable somethingDoable) {
    somethingDoable.doSomething();
}
```

Using it is as simple as this:

```
doSomething(new StringDoable("42"));
doSomething(new IntegerDoable(42));
```

The main advantage with this approach is ... Extending this simply means to add another concrete class. No need to change anything else.

Comment: Haha, we arrive at very similar solutions from very different paths!

Comment: @Sweeper Well ... OOP sometimes is a straight path. :-) Seriously: This conceptual thinking is a very important learning step.

Answer (score 2):

At runtime, Java dynamically dispatches methods only based on the object on which you called the method, i.e. `this` from the callee's perspective, aka the "receiver parameter", or whatever you call this part of the call:

```
animal.eat(food);
^^^^^^

this.someMethod(input);
^^^^
```

Which method is chosen at runtime solely depends on that part. If `foo` at runtime stores an instance of `Dog`, then `Dog.eat` is called. If it stores an instance of `Cat`, then `Cat.eat` is called.

However, what you want to do here seems to be dynamic dispatch based on what type `food` stores at runtime. Since Java doesn't do that, you either have to dispatch it manually with a chain of if-else-ifs, or change the call so that `food` is the receiver:

```
food.getsEatenBy(animal);

input.someMethod(this); // not sure if your someMethod needs "this" or not...
```

Since the parameters in your case are `String` and `Integer`, you need to write wrapper classes for them in order to be able to add methods to them.

```
// let's also introduce an interface that all the inputs of someMethod implements
public interface SomeMethodInput {
    // SomeMethodClass is the class where someMethod originally was
    void someMethod(SomeMethodClass self);
}

public class StringInput implements SomeMethodInput {

    private String value;

    public StringInput(String string) {
        this.value = string;
    }


    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    @Override
    public void someMethod(SomeMethodClass self) {
        // do string things...
    }
}

public class IntegerInput implements SomeMethodInput {

    private Integer value;

    public IntegerInput(Integer integer) {
        this.value = integer;
    }

    public Integer getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    @Override
    public void someMethod(SomeMethodClass self) {
        // do integer things...
    }
}
```

Now `doSomething` just needs to take a `SomeMethodInput`:

```
public void doSomething(SomeMethodInput input) {
    input.someMethod(this);
}
```

You might notice some similarities between this and the visitor pattern, and you'd be right - this is exactly how the visitor pattern achieves double dispatch, on both `this`, and the parameter. What I have shown here is not quite that yet, because it only dispatches on the parameter.

Comment: Yeah ... very nice. :-)